# Unable to Switch to other PostgreSQL DB using Protractor (pg node module)

Tags: postgresql, npm, protractor

I am using connection string as below and able to connect to default DB
postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres

But my tables exist in the DB under the default postgres DB which is for e.g. "database_xyz".  I need to switch to this DB while connected to postgres.

from psql we do

```
postgres=# \c database_xyz
```

Tried different options like by giving this database name end of the line in the connection string but it says doesn't exist or prints undefined in console

Also tried `SET search_path TO 'database_xyz';`    (doesn't work either)

Tried using pgstructure node module as well (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-structure)

Comment: One connection is always tied to exactly one database. You can't switch between databases on the same connection - you need to create a new connection if you want to use a different database. `search_path` is only for _schemas_ not for databases

Comment: thanks for the response a_horse but my 2nd DB is not independent we have to connect through postgres only. Am I missing something? can you please give me an example

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "not independent", but as I said: you have to create a second/new connection if you want to access a different database. You can **not** just "switch" the database on one connection.

Comment: Is it possible to provide connection string through JDBC by any chance? by installing any node module?

Comment: you apparently already know how to create a connection. Just use that code to create a new connection to the other database.

Comment: I am giving connectionstring and connectionString1 and then doing const client = new pg.Client(connectionString)  and repeat same for other. but getting pg.Client1 is not a constructor? please advise

Comment: Edit : I am using following code (if I have to create a new connection can you please advise what changes I have to make)
const connectingString = "postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres";
const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
  client.connect();
  client.on('error', err => console.log('ERR|> ', err));
  client.query('select * from org.emp')`enter code here`
      .then(res => console.log('RES|> ', res.rows))
      .then(() => process.exit(0))
      .catch(err => console.log('QERR|>', err));

Comment: My Bad. the database name was case sensitive. it worked finally. please ignore